# Rails: How to use link_to with api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to add a link to cancel a Braintree subscription. According to braintree references I have to use `Braintree::Subscription.cancel(# here is placed the braintree_subscription_id)`

In order to achieve this I'm using the following code:

views/accounts/show.html.erb

`<%= link_to 'Cancel Subscription', Braintree::Subscription.cancel(@braintree_subscription_id) %>`

accounts_controller.rb

```
def show
  @accounts = Account.find(params[:id])
  @braintree_subscription_id = current_store.braintree_subscription_id
end
```

But an error appears `undefined method to_model for #<Braintree::ErrorResult:0x007fee12083e98>
Did you mean?  to_yaml`

What am I doing wrong?? Any ideas?

**Update 1**

Log when I click cancel subscription, after I updated the code according to @Pavan code.

```
Started GET "/cancel_subscription" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-26 13:37:30 +0300
(0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by AccountsController#cancel_subscription as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1005ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



Braintree::NotFoundError (subscription with id nil not found):

app/controllers/accounts_controller.rb:17:in `cancel_subscription'
```

Comment: "Braintree::NotFoundError (subscription with id nil not found)" - your variable there, it's nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just give an **API method** as a *path* to a `link_to`. You should define a **custom route** for a `controller#action` and perform the logic in the method.

```
#routes.rb
get "/cancel_subscription/:subscription_id", to: "accounts#cancel_subscription", as: "cancel_subscription"
```

And have your `link_to` like so

```
<%= link_to 'Cancel Subscription', cancel_subscription_path(subscription_id: @braintree_subscription_id) %>
```

Finally in the controller

```
def cancel_subscription
  result = Braintree::Subscription.cancel(params[:subscription_id])
  redirect_to "your desired path"
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Pavan! All works well up until i click on `cancel subscription`... this error appears `subscription with id nil not found` the error is at this line `result = Braintree::Subscription.cancel(params[:subscription_id])`

Comment: @Devup That means `@braintree_subscription_id` is nil. Inspect the value of `current_store.braintree_subscription_id`. What it returns?

Comment: @Devup Can you post the log when you click on the link?

Comment: Sure!! I just did @Pavan.

Comment: @Devup Ok. Try changing the route to `get "/cancel_subscription/:subscription_id", to: "accounts#cancel_subscription", as: "cancel_subscription"` and check again

Comment: for some reason I thought that I had to delete the `@braintree_subscription_id = current_store.braintree_subscription_id` inside the show method. Once I've put back there it worked just fine. Thanks!!!!